# ¿Cuándo se debería usar img y cuando background-image?

Tags: html, css, html5

En programación web, se puede poner una imagen con la etiqueta `img` o como imagen de fondo usando `background-image` en CSS y el resultado será visualmente similar:

```css
.hamburguesa {
  background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/tbhsHbKh.jpg);
  width:256px;
  height:256px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/tbhsHbKh.jpg" alt="Hamburguesa" />

<div class="hamburguesa"></div>
```

¿Qué ventajas tiene usar una sobre la otra? ¿En qué situaciones se debería usar `img` y en cuáles se debería usar `background-image`?

Factores a tener en cuenta: usabilidad, accesibilidad, adaptabilidad, tipo de visualización (pantalla, impresora, etc).

Comment: Siempre haciendo buenas preguntas @AlvaroMontoro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Todo depende del propósito que tengas para la imagen:

**`IMG`**

- Utiliza `IMG` si pretendes que la gente imprima la página y deseas que la imagen que sea incluida por defecto.
- Utiliza `IMG`(con `alt`) cuando la imagen tiene un importante significado semántico, tal como un icono de advertencia. Esto asegura que el significado de la imagen sea comunicado a todos los agentes de uso, incluyendo lectores de pantalla.
- Utiliza `IMG`si deseas que el navegador muestre una imagen en proporción al tamaño del texto.
- Utiliza `IMG`para múltiples imágenes superpuestas en IE6.
- Usar `IMG`en vez de background-image puede mejorar drásticamente el rendimiento de las animaciones sobre un fondo.

**`CSS background-image`**

- Utiliza `CSS background-image` si la imagen no es parte del contenido.
- Utiliza `CSS background-image` cuando la imagen sustituye al texto
- Utiliza `CSS background-image` si pretendes que la gente imprima la página y NO deseas que la imagen que sea incluida por defecto.
- Utiliza `CSS background-image` si es necesario mejorar los tiempos de descarga.
- Utiliza `CSS background-image` si es necesario hacer visible solo una parte de la imagen.
- Utiliza `CSS background-image` combinado con `CSS background-size:cover` con el fin de estirar una imagen de fondo para cubrir la totalidad del contenedor (ej div, body, etc..).

Comment: Podías poner la fuente de tu respuesta, quizá los que saben inglés quieran ver el original: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image#1469139

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar el punto de "_Utiliza CSS background-image cuando la imagen sustituye al texto_"?

Comment: Fuente http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image
no hice una traducción literal, corregí algunos puntos según mi propia experiencia.

Comment: "Utiliza CSS background-image cuando la imagen sustituye al texto" - Por ejemplo, si creas un Botón tipo <ul><li> y en vez de ponerle un texto pondrás una imagen que representa su acción, mejor utiliza CSS background-image. Así manejas tu botón como un solo objeto, además de las ventajas para el ajuste del tamaño de la imagen según su contenedor

Comment: Gracias por poner la fuente original. En el texto (en [un comentario en la propia respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image/492834#comment13141593_492834)) parece que se dice que el texto se mantiene en la página pero se oculta con CSS (manteniendo la misma estructura y semántica HTML en la página)

Comment: Eso es @AlvaroMontoro . Antes era muy típico por ejemplo poner el logo en un `h1` y se ponía el nombre de la web/empresa en él pero se ocultaba con un `text-indent` negativo o algún truco similar y el logo iba como una imagen de fondo, si el css no carga se ve el texto, los lectores de pantalla y buscadores también pueden ver el texto. También se reemplazaban textos por imágenes para usar tipográfias extrañas cuando no había `@font-face`. Por la forma en que maquetamos hoy en día muchas de estás técnicas han quedado obsoletas aunque siguen siendo válidas.

Comment: @MarcoSánchez Trata siempre de poner la fuente en tu respuesta por cuestiones éticas. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Cuándo se debería usar `img` y cuando `background-image`?

Bueno cuando se debería usar, aquí depende dependería mucho del proyecto o del diseño.

**Ejemplos:**

- Se suele usar `background-image` en un div de un personaje u imagen que representen la empresa o de un producto con un texto corto descriptivo.
- Se suele usar también para crear un efecto de animación jQuery tipo: Fixed Background Scrolling entre otros.
- Se suele usar para crear un color de fondo con un diseño ilustrativo.

Uno de los temas de mucho interés y de gran ventaja es cuando la imagen tiene una resolución demasiada extensa y aplicar resolución responsive no se adapta al gusto es decir las dimensiones se hacen demasiadas pequeñas en ciertas partes o aveces un efecto borroso.

Ejemplo `background-image`:

```css
#image {
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-image:url(http://www.hrhwalls.com/reimg/image.php?src=http://img.hrhwalls.com/images178/0bdvpx5pom5.jpg&h=900&w=1600);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0% 75%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="image"></div>
```

La ventaja es que se adapta a un responsive pero se rescata cierta parte de la imagen ocultando cierto contenido no deseado cambiándole el valor de `background-position` importante agregar esta propiedad `background-size: cover;` para su funcionamiento.

Mientras que en una imagen `img` si cambias el valor del `height: auto;` a un  `height: 600px;` si observas la diferencia al cambiar el valor este ya no ocupa el 100% del sitio y si cambias por pinceles el `width` para ocupar el 100% del sitio se perdería el responsive.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  /*height: auto;*/
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.hrhwalls.com/reimg/image.php?src=http://img.hrhwalls.com/images178/0bdvpx5pom5.jpg&h=900&w=1600" alt="" />
```

Sobre cuando usar `img` más corresponde como ejemplo un producto la cual muestra una imagen representadora, o al igual del logotipo de la empresa o del sitio.

> La mayor parte del sitio utiliza más `background-image` en lo personal a mi me gusta utilizar más `background-image`.

**Desventajas de:** `background-image`

Una de las desventaja de `background-image` es que no existe posicionamiento seo en imágenes. Porqué las imágenes de fondo no tiene atributo `alt` el google y las recomendaciones de seo es que para posicionamiento seo en las imágenes es darle nombre al atributo `alt="Foro stackoverflow"`

**Ventajas de:** `img`

Es que si posee posicionamiento seo en las imágenes con el atributo `alt="stackoverflow"`. Esto ara más fácil encontrar el nombre de tu empresa entre mas espacio ganes en posicionamiento seo mucho mejor.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con el posicionamiento seo al final de la respuesta?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Hola, las imágenes de fondo no tiene atributo `alt` por lo tanto no tiene posicionamiento seo en las imágenes llamadas normalmente de esta manera sí tendrá  posicionamiento seo `<img src="" alt="Mi encontraran en google" />`

Comment: ¿Tienes una fuenta para eso? Tenía entendido que Google no sólo indexaba por el alt sino también por el contenido de la página en sí

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro [10 claves de SEO para imágenes](http://luismvillanueva.com/seo/seo-imagenes-10-claves.html) y lo que nos comenta [Google Image Search](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016?hl=es) Por otra parte si Google indexara todo el contenido las imágenes de fondos quedarían en un fondo vació no es lo mismo buscar una imagen que tiene un nombre como buscarlas ejemplo alt="stackoverflow" .

Comment: Gracias! Voy a mirar los enlaces :)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro de nada amigo me comentas luego vale :) amigo en algunas preguntas me haz solucionado mis problemas [Puedes echar un vistazo a mi pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23944/error-en-variable-global-no-almacena-las-etiquetas-tags-añadidas-por-los-usuar) si puedes ayudarme te agradecería :)

Comment: Ahora lo miro, parece que tienes dos buenas respuestas, ¿no te sirvieron?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro una de las respuestas está sólo programada sólo con javascript para futuros lectores estará muy bien, la otra respuesta está muy bien pero no almacena los datos en la variable global y el efecto para añadir las etiquetas tags sería confuso para los usuarios porque tienen que escribir la etiqueta y dar clic fuera del input para que se agregué la etiqueta entonces lo ideal sería añadir la etiqueta automáticamente separadas por una coma encontré la documentación en la pregunta esta incluída los códigos necesarios pero no se como implementarlos en el código.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro por cierto amigo que te pareció los enlace sobre el tema de Seo de las imágenes, sólo quiero que comprendas que no es lo mismo buscar a una persona con nombres y apellidos que buscar a otra persona donde no se sabe los nombres algo así parecido funciona el Seo en las imágenes con el atributo **alt** con el atributo **alt** la imagen toma vida porqué tiene un nombre cómo encontrarla en los buscadores en cambió las imágenes de fondo sería más difícil encontrarlas porque ni posee un nombre específico para buscarla espero me entiendas amigo :)

Answer (score 1):

Usa **img** para lo que es, añadir una imagen literalmente.

Usa **background-image** cuando quieras poner una imagen de fondo de algún elemento, como por ejemplo a un div.

Usemos las cosas para lo que han sido hechas :)

Comment: ¿Qué usarías para el logo de una empresa o de un sitio web?¿Y para el icono que acompaña a un botón/enlace?¿Y para un banner?¿Qué pasa si por cualquier motivo la hoja de estilos no carga?¿Y si quieres animar la imagen y/o añadir transiciones? La línea entre `img` y `background-image` puede ser borrosa en algunos casos y algo más complicado que simplemente "usa img para una imagen". Por esa regla de tres, las imágenes de fondo también son imágenes, ¿por qué no ponerlas con un `img` también en lugar de usar `background-image`?

Comment: La linea que las puede diferenciar puede ser muy delgada, si, pero no hay que olvidar para que son cada cosa. 
La etiqueta **img** según la documentación html es para representar una imagen, y la propiedad de css **background-image** según la documentación es para establecer una imagen de fondo en un elemento. El mejor ejemplo lo tienes con la propiedad float, se usaba para hacer responsive los sitios y que las cajas fueran flexibles, pero esa no era su función aunque se usara,  por eso se creó flexbox.
Un clavo también se clava con un libro, pero no es su verdadera función

Answer (score 0):

Background-image: Mayormente se utiliza para que una caja o contenido del html introduzca una imagen de fondo.

Img: Se utiliza para colocar imagenes, ya se como blog, logos, galerias entre otras cosas.

Answer (score 0):

Mi respuesta es vista desde el uso pragmático y con énfasis al SEO, más allá de lo que es posible teóricamente con cada elemento.

Recomendaría en mayor medida usar `img` y usar con cuidado `background-image` porque este supone ser un contenido de menor importancia.

### **`img`**

- Usa `img` cuando necesites que los motores de búsqueda rastreen la imagen usando las etiquetas `alt` y `title`. Vas a querer que la mayoría del tiempo tus imágenes sean rastreadas, por supuesto tienen que ser parte del contenido.
- Usa `img` cuando la imagen sea compleja o grande.

### **`background-image`**

- Usa `background-image` para imágenes simples como texturas o decoraciones. Estas imágenes no son rastreadas por los motores de búsqueda por lo que con un peso mayor considerable no suelen ser rentables para la web ya que reducen el rendimiento.
- Usa `background-image` para imágenes complejas que no son parte del contenido. Un ejemplo común es una imagen de terceras personas que a veces incluso tiene un filtro opaco, no es recomendable usar esta imagen pero a veces es buena idea porque agrega cierto atractivo al sitio.

### Importante considerar

- Aunque `img` y `background-image` pueden usarse para imágenes complejas como fotos del mundo real, evita usar estas imágenes sobre todo con `background-image` porque además de aumentar el peso de la web no suelen ser rentables en este último caso ya que no son rastreadas por los motores de búsqueda.
- Hoy en día es muy común usar `background-image` con un fondo cada vez más complejo y esto es lo que provoca la confusión o línea delgada entre usar `img` o `background-image` cuando inicialmente `background-image` debería ser para imágenes simples. Sin embargo, como **excepción** a veces sirve de utilidad cuando se quieren mostrar imágenes complejas que no son parte del contenido pero agregan atractivo al sitio web.
- Con lo anterior se puede deducir que usar `img` suele ser más útil que `background-image` y que esta última es sólo una utilidad de diseño ya que directamente no es importante para el contenido según SEO y su uso debe ser controlado a criterio o mediante pruebas A/B con ayuda de herramientas como Google Analytics.

Ejemplo de buen uso de `background-image`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A excepción de que no es una imagen simple, es buena implementación porque no abarca gran espacio y por lo tanto no suele ser pesada, además no es parte del contenido.