# Refactorización de triángulo cambia colores

Tags: javascript, css

¿Cómo puedo mejorar este código? ¿Hay algún evento para cambiar de color?

No quiero usar estas condiciones `if(color==0){`, ¿Cuál sería otra forma de resolverlo?

```js
var flecha=document.getElementById("flecha")
var color=0;
flecha.onclick = function() {
 if(color==0){ 
   this.style.borderBottom ="100px solid red";
   this.style.borderLeft ="50px solid transparent";
   this.style.borderRight ="50px solid transparent";
   color=1;
 }else{
   this.style.borderBottom ="100px solid #3af";
   this.style.borderLeft ="50px solid transparent";
   this.style.borderRight ="50px solid transparent";
   color=0;
 }
 }
```

```css
#flecha{
  border-bottom:100px solid #3af;
  border-left:50px solid transparent;
  border-right:50px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="flecha"> </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ya que solo necesitas cambiar el color del borde inferior y el resto de propiedades se mantiene igual solo deberías actualizar la propiedad `this.style.borderBottomColor`.

Además en lugar de un `if` podrías usar una operación matemática muy simple para dar vueltas dentro de un arreglo de colores: Sumar +1 para ir al color de la derecha y hallar el residio entre el número de elementos para dar la vuelta si se acaban los colores.

PD: También si deseas puedes agregar mas colores al arreglo sin necesidad de modificar el resto del código.

```js
var colors = ["#3af", "red", "yellow", "magenta", "cyan"];
var selectedColor = 0;

document.getElementById("flecha").onclick = function() {
    selectedColor = (selectedColor + 1) % colors.length;
    this.style.borderBottomColor = colors[selectedColor];
}
```

```css
#flecha{
    border-bottom: 100px solid #3af;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="flecha"> </div>
```